# session attribute receive null when crossing diffrent request in spring boot

Tags: java

heres my code

```
@Autowired
HttpSession httpSession;

@GetMapping("/getproductlist")
@CrossOrigin
@ResponseBody
public Map<String,Object> getproductlist(HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession session)
{
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    shop currshop = new shop();
    currshop.setShop_id(1l);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("currshop",currshop);
    httpSession.setAttribute("currshop",currshop);


    shop currshop2 = (com.o2o.shop.entity.shop) httpSession.getAttribute("currshop");

    System.out.println("===================="+currshop2.getShop_id());

    List<productCategory> list = null;

    if(currshop2 != null && currshop2.getShop_id() != null)
    {
        list = pcategoryService.queryProductCategoryList(currshop.getShop_id());
        map.put("pcategory",list);
    }else{
        map.put("success",false);
    }
    return map;
}
```

its works if in this request
but its always null when i try next request

```
@PostMapping(value = "/insertBatch")
@CrossOrigin
@ResponseBody
public Map<String,Object> insertBatch(@RequestBody List<productCategory> pcategory,HttpServletRequest request)  {
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    int a =-1;
    shop currshop2 = (com.o2o.shop.entity.shop) httpSession.getAttribute("currshop");

    System.out.println("===================="+currshop2 .getShop_id());

    for(productCategory pc : pcategory)
    {
        pc.setShop_id(currshop2 .getShop_id());
    }
    if(pcategory != null && pcategory.size() != 0)
    {
        a = pcategoryService.insertBatch(pcategory);
        map.put("success",a);
    }else{
        a=0;
        map.put("success","empty list");
    }
    return map;
}
```

is it browser problem or i missing something?
heres the error list

```
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:517)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1656)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:292)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null

i was try to fix this issue for 2 day.but i cant not figure out why i
always can not get session attribute when trying to get diffrerent page
and fetch the right attribute